# UICollectionView embedded in UICollectionViewCell acting weird with UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a `UINavigationController` that has a `UIViewController` at its root. I have a `UICollectionView` that fills the `UIViewController`. My look that I'm trying to go for is a navigation bar that hovers over this collection view. For this I have pinned the `UICollectionView` to the top of the superview instead of to the top of the `Safe Area`. I've also turned off `adjust scroll view insets`.

Inside my collection view I have a cell that has a `UICollectionView` embedded in it. When I start scrolling, the embedded `UICollectionView` seems to decrease in size slightly as it goes past the `UINavigationBar`. I should note that if I instead pin my outer `UICollectionView` to the `Safe Area`, this problem doesn't occur!

How can I solve this? Is there a better way to make the `UICollectionView` ignore the nav bar instead of pinning it to the top of the superview?

Comment: Can u post screenshot ?? how u r facing error ?

Comment: Did you solved it?

Comment: @RoiMulia I can't really remember for this specific question, but whenever I have had this issue I always make sure everything is pinned to the superview and not to use the safe area!